# I tried with String Split with Varying number of elements in each row of data. I am not able to trace NULL at the end

Tags: string, split

Trying to read from a data file with number of rows of data and each row the number of elements are varying.

```
        StreamReader read = new StreamReader("TextFile1.txt");

        string str1 = " ";
        while (str1 != null)
        {
            str1 = read.ReadLine();
            if (str1 != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\n"+str1);
                string[] s = str1.Split(' ');
                i = 0;
                sum = 0;
                while (s[i] != null)
                {
                    if(i>0)
                        j=int.Parse(s[i]);
                    sum = sum + j;
                    i = i + 1;

                } 


            }

        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a language tag to it.

Comment: Looks C#. OP. OP, please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the code you posted is C#, you should use the `String.length` property.

Just a snippet of that from the inside of your loop:

```
            string[] s = str1.Split(' ');
            i = 0;
            sum = 0;
            while (i < s.length)
            {
                j=int.Parse(s[i]);
                sum = sum + j;
                i = i + 1;

            }
```

By the way, I removed the `if(i > 0)` condition as it seems rather unnecessary. However, if you would like to exclude the first element on the line (which is what the *`if(i>0)`* condition was doing), then simply change `i = 0;` to `i = 1;`.